# UIWebView in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: html, swift3, uiwebview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UIwebView inside UICollectionviewCell to display some dynamic html content coming from server. In my UICollectionViewCell subclass I am loading html content as following

```
 let mainbundle = Bundle.main.bundlePath
 let bundleURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: mainbundle)
 webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL:  bundleURL as URL)
```

Inside webViewDidFinishLoad() function

```
let fittingSize = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
 webView.frame.size.height = fittingSize.height
```

But my UICollectionViewCell is not scaling itself according to the webView height and webView starts overlapping other views inside the cell. I tried almost every solution available over internet but none of them worked for me.

I also tried loading my html content in UITextView using NSAttributedString but it seems like it does not support all css properties.

Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks